# Get top 1 row of each group using Kusto

Tags: group-by, azure-data-explorer, kql, partition-by, kusto-explorer

I have a table which I would like to get the latest entry for each group using Kusto Query Language. Here's the table:

DocumentStatusLogs

| ID | DocumentID | Status | DateCreated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 | S1 | 7/29/2011 |
| 3 | 1 | S2 | 7/30/2011 |
| 6 | 1 | S1 | 8/02/2011 |
| 1 | 2 | S1 | 7/28/2011 |
| 4 | 2 | S2 | 7/30/2011 |
| 5 | 2 | S3 | 8/01/2011 |
| 6 | 3 | S1 | 8/02/2011 |

The table would be grouped by DocumentID and sorted by DateCreated in descending order. For each DocumentID, I want to get the latest status.

My preferred output:

| DocumentID | Status | DateCreated |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | S1 | 8/02/2011 |
| 2 | S3 | 8/01/2011 |
| 3 | S1 | 8/02/2011 |

Is there any way to get only the top from each group using KQL?

The pseudo-code GetOnlyTheTop is as follows:

```
SELECT
  DocumentID,
  GetOnlyTheTop(Status),
  GetOnlyTheTop(DateCreated)
FROM DocumentStatusLogs
GROUP BY DocumentID
ORDER BY DateCreated DESC
```

Credit: Question adapted from DPP's SQL question: [Get top 1 row of each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841605/get-top-1-row-of-each-group)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use the [`partition` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/partitionoperator), or the [`arg_max()`  aggregation function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/arg-max-aggfunction).

For example:

```
DocumentStatusLogs
| partition by DocumentId
(
    top 1 by DateCreated desc
)
```

Or

```
DocumentStatusLogs
| summarize arg_max(DateCreated, *) by DocumentId
```

Comment: I just realized that the `partition` operator was enhanced and now supports limitless partitions (and not just 64). Amazing improvement for KQL. Thanks Yoni! :-)

Comment: @DavidדודוMarkovitz - it does not actually. Just got the error message `partition operator: exceeded amount of maximum partitions allowed (64)`

Comment: as mentioned in [the documentation for the `partition` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/partitionoperator), the limit on 64 partitions still exists for the Legacy strategy. you can use a different strategy (e.g. `native`) if required