# Finding greatest count of each distinct column value

Tags: kql

Given a table like below, is it possible in Kusto get the row with the greatest count for each food?

Person  Food    NumEaten

```
a   cake    28
b   cake    6
c   cake    3
d   cake    2
e   cake    2
f   pie     117
g   pie     79
h   pie     41
i   pie     35
```

Result to achieve:

```
Person  Food    NumEaten

a   cake    28
f   pie     117
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `arg_max()` aggregation function or the `partition` operator. See similar post here: [Get top 1 row of each group using Kusto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71611379/get-top-1-row-of-each-group-using-kusto#71611507)

Comment: Partition is exactly what I was looking for!  I was scouring around trying to find a way to "loop" through values.